# How we get last editable row data in datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I Create last row in datagrid but cannot capture its data when i edit it.
    `private void Save_row_data(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = grid_deduction.SelectedItem as Deductions;
            //DataGridRow gridRow = grid_deduction.r as Deductions;
            MessageBox.Show(row.card_no);
        }`

In it Deductions is class and card_no its get,sett method.

Comment: check if grid_deduction.SelectedItem and row have desired value.

Comment: I check all things but newly add row data capture by button but does not capture by using ctrl+S